# How can I change my bone positions after parenting objects to the bone?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I laid out all the bones in my armature and parented the parts of my model to the bones. So far so good. But, when setting constraints on one of the bones in Pose Mode, I noticed that it was slightly out of position. I opened the armature in Edit Mode and moved the bone into the correct position, but when I went back into Pose Mode the object parented to that bone had also moved. Now it's moved no matter what mode I'm in.

How can I make changes like this to my armature without it affecting Pose Mode? I am using Blender 2.93.

Here's a picture of my problem:

[image]

This is the upper arm of a robot. As you can see, the shoulder has its own bone that connects to the upper arm bone. The shoulder should be able to rotate 360 on the X axis, but nothing else. The upper arm should be able to rotate 90 on the Y axis but nothing else.

The problem came when I noticed the tail of the shoulder bone was not aligned with its head on Y axis. This made the bone crooked, causing the shoulder to rotate off-axis. When I went into Edit Mode and dragged the shoulder bone's tail into alignment with its head, the shoulder and upper arm rotations shifted inexplicably. The shoulder is tilted forward slightly on the X axis, and the upper arm is noticeably tilted back. Without posing, these parts should stand straight up (vertical lines should be 90 degrees). If I delete the armature, the parts revert to their correct positions. Removing the bone constraint doesn't change anything.

Comment: if you give a constraint to a bone it may move in Pose mode because it can make it stick to its target, so you need to make sure that it already sticks in Edit mode. It looks like you've already correct that, so maybe share your file or at least show some pictures so that we understand the problem more precisely?

Comment: @moonboots I have added a picture and more detailed explanation.